# Why are rows duplicated after inserting in my ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am adding rows (1D Array of strings) in my ArrayList. I am printing it, beforehand entering to maake sure, the rows entered in arraylist is correct.

Surprise is: On printing my arraylist, i can see, the last row entered is getting printed always, and not the other rows.

Here is the code:

```
try {
    while(rs.next())
    {
        for(int i=0; i< parameters.length; i++)
        {
            recordSet[i] = rs.getString(parameters[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("After for loop" + " "+ recordSet[0] +" "+ recordSet[1]+ " " +recordSet[2]);
        ar.add(recordSet);

    }
    System.out.println("Printing the arraylist");
    for (String[] arr : ar) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
} 
catch (SQLException e){ 
    e.printStackTrace();
    log.error("extractValues: Exception caught while iterating resultSet" + e.toString());
}


Output is:
 After for loop 0 1 rakesh123
 After for loop 0 2 raj123

Printing the arraylist
[0, 2, raj123]
[0, 2, raj123]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the same array reference for `recordSet` when you add it to the `List`.

```
while(rs.next())
{
    String[] recordSet = new String[paramters.length]; // <-- make a new one.
    for(int i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++)
    {
        recordSet[i] = rs.getString(parameters[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("After for loop " + recordSet[0] 
        + " " + recordSet[1] + " " + recordSet[2]);
    ar.add(recordSet);
}
```

Make sure you comment out the other `recordSet` declaration.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand, i thought the old entries would be overwritten, won't it?

Comment: Yes, **but** there is only one array. So when you overwrite the values, you also modify the one in your `List`. You've been adding the same reference multiple times to the `List`.

Answer (score 2):

assign new recordset object  to reference in while loop and check

```
while(rs.next())
{
   recordSet = new String[paramters.length];
    for(int i=0; i< parameters.length; i++)
    {
        recordSet[i] = rs.getString(parameters[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("After for loop" + " "+ recordSet[0] +" "+ recordSet[1]+ " " +recordSet[2]);
    ar.add(recordSet);

}
```